# How to rename a file using svn?

Tags: svn

When I try `svn mv old_file_name new_file_name`, I get

```
 svn: Path 'new_file_name' is not a directory
```

What's the correct way? (sorry, this seems so trivial, but I'm stuck).

PS. using svn version 1.6.11

**EDIT** it seems I get this error only if `new_file_name` refers to the name of a file that is currently under version control. In this case, of course, I can simply

```
 mv old_file_name new_file_name
 svn delete old_file_name
```

Comment: Maybe you need the full repository path, `file://...` or `svn://...` or `http://...` to the file.

Answer (score 125, accepted):

The behaviour differs depending on whether the target file name already exists or not. It's usually a safety mechanism, and there are at least 3 different cases:

### Target file does *not* exist:

In this case `svn mv` should work as follows:

```
$ svn mv old_file_name new_file_name
A         new_file_name
D         old_file_name
$ svn stat
A  +    new_file_name
        > moved from old_file_name
D       old_file_name
        > moved to new_file_name
$ svn commit
Adding     new_file_name
Deleting   old_file_name
Committing transaction...
```

### Target file already exists in repository:

In this case, the target file needs to be removed explicitly, before the source file can be renamed. This can be done in the same transaction as follows:

```
$ svn mv old_file_name new_file_name 
svn: E155010: Path 'new_file_name' is not a directory
$ svn rm new_file_name 
D         new_file_name
$ svn mv old_file_name new_file_name 
A         new_file_name
D         old_file_name
$ svn stat
R  +    new_file_name
        > moved from old_file_name
D       old_file_name
        > moved to new_file_name
$ svn commit
Replacing      new_file_name
Deleting       old_file_name
Committing transaction...
```

In the output of `svn stat`, the `R` indicates that the file has been replaced, and that the file has a history.

### Target file already exists *locally* (unversioned):

In this case, the content of the local file would be lost. If that's okay, then the file can be removed locally before renaming the existing file.

```
$ svn mv old_file_name new_file_name 
svn: E155010: Path 'new_file_name' is not a directory
$ rm new_file_name 
$ svn mv old_file_name new_file_name 
A         new_file_name
D         old_file_name
$ svn stat
A  +    new_file_name
        > moved from old_file_name
D       old_file_name
        > moved to new_file_name
$ svn commit
Adding         new_file_name
Deleting       old_file_name
Committing transaction...
```

Comment: I needed to add --force to svn rm new_file_name as it complained that new_file is is not under version control.

Comment: .. and I had to create an empty file called new_file_name.

Comment: on 1.8.3 rm removes the physical file, just running the "svn mv ..." was sufficient, it executes that A D.

Comment: It is funny how old SVN is and how awkward it is to rename a file using it.

Comment: @Ghasan: The title of the question might be misleading. It's about *removing* one file and *renaming* another file at the same time. This use case is not that common, and a bit tricky with most VCS, in particular if the information should be visible in the history.

Comment: For me simply typing `svn mv old_file_name new_file_name` did the trick.  Then I checked it with `stat` and committed it. (I was renaming a file, that already existed.)  Very helpful, thank you.

Answer (score 18):

Using TortoiseSVN worked easily on Windows for me.

http://tortoisesvn.net/

Right click file -> TortoiseSVN menu -> Repo-browser -> right click file in repository -> rename -> press Enter -> click Ok

Using SVN 1.8.8
TortoiseSVN version 1.8.5

Comment: Not that the OP was asking about Windows, but upvotes deserve extension: Full desktop integration means that you may simply do this in the context menu from Explorer.

Comment: But now I see that posting a Windows answer on what is clearly a Linux question has gotten this one down-voted several time. (drats, time ran out for me to edit my original comment)

Comment: I was using Cygwin on Windows at the time, so there was some crossover.

Comment: I couldn't get it to work without using TortoiseSVN on Windows. So I am thankful for this answer. I upvoted you. Using anything else kept causing it to revert anytime I updated. In my case the change was capitalization of the file names. I think the issue in my case stems from the fact  that Windows is case insensitive.

Comment: This worls, but you will lose the history of the file.

Comment: Then, what happen with users that have `old_file_name` on their working copy?

Answer (score 8):

This message will appear if you are using a case-insensitive file system (e.g. on a Mac) and you're trying to capitalize the name (or another change of case).
In which case you need to rename to a third, dummy, name:

```
svn mv file-name file-name_
svn mv file-name_ FILE_Name
svn commit
```

Comment: And I was wondering why it works on Linux but not on Mac. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It can be if you created new directory at the disk BEFORE create/commit it in the SVN. All that you need is just create it in SVN and do move after:

```
$ svn mv etc/nagios/hosts/us0101/cs/us0101ccs001.cfg etc/nagios/hosts/us0101/ccs/
svn: E155010: Path '/home/dyr/svn/nagioscore/etc/nagios/hosts/us0101/ccs' is not a directory

$ svn status
?       etc/nagios/hosts/us0101/ccs

$ rm -rvf etc/nagios/hosts/us0101/ccs
removed directory 'etc/nagios/hosts/us0101/ccs'

$ svn mkdir etc/nagios/hosts/us0101/ccs
A         etc/nagios/hosts/us0101/ccs

$ svn move etc/nagios/hosts/us0101/cs/us0101ccs001.cfg etc/nagios/hosts/us0101/ccs/us0101accs001.cfg
A         etc/nagios/hosts/us0101/ccs/us0101accs001.cfg
D         etc/nagios/hosts/us0101/cs/us0101ccs001.cfg

$ svn status
A       etc/nagios/hosts/us0101/ccs
A  +    etc/nagios/hosts/us0101/ccs/us0101accs001.cfg
        > moved from etc/nagios/hosts/us0101/cs/us0101ccs001.cfg
D       etc/nagios/hosts/us0101/cs/us0101ccs001.cfg
        > moved to etc/nagios/hosts/us0101/ccs/us0101accs001.cfg
```